# How do i output XMLTrees in HXT?

Tags: xml, haskell, hxt

I am trying to extract tags from a xml file and write each one to a seperate file based on an attribute.

The extraction part isn't that hard:

```
*Main> ifs <- runX ( readDocument [withCurl [],withExpat yes] "file.xml" >>> getElement "TagName" >>> getAttrValue "Name" &&& this)
*Main> :t ifs
ifs :: [(String, XmlTree)]
```

I tried to map writeDocument over the second entries but had no sucess. I understand that i have to get it back into the IO Monad somehow ... but have no idea on how to achieve this.

---

for testing purposes i have extracted on of those XmlTrees from the result:

```
*Main> let x = (map snd ifs) !! 0
*Main> :t x
x :: XmlTree
```

I can run arrows on `x` like this:

```
*Main> runLA (getName) x
["TagName"]
```

But when i try to write it to a file i get error message indicating that i am not in the IO Monade (i think):

```
*Main> runLA (writeDocument [] "test.xml") x

<interactive>:1:8:
    Couldn't match expected type `LA a0 b0'
                with actual type `IOSLA (XIOState s0) XmlTree XmlTree'
    Expected type: LA a0 b0
      Actual type: IOStateArrow s0 XmlTree XmlTree
    In the return type of a call of `writeDocument'
    In the first argument of `runLA', namely
      `(writeDocument [] "test.xml")'
```

Changing `runLA` to `runIOSLA` doesn't help:

```
*Main> runIOSLA (writeDocument [] "test.xml") x

<interactive>:1:40:
    Couldn't match expected type `XIOState s0'
            with actual type `Data.Tree.NTree.TypeDefs.NTree XNode'
    Expected type: XIOState s0
      Actual type: XmlTree
    In the second argument of `runIOSLA', namely `x'
    In the expression: runIOSLA (writeDocument [] "test.xml") x
```

---

That's as far as i can get.

### Update

As Travis Brown points out it is possible to do this in one arrow:

```
runX . applyA $ readDocument [withCurl [],withExpat yes] "file.xml" >>> getElement "Tag" >>> getAttrValue "DEF" &&& this >>> arr (\ (n,x) -> root [] [constA x] >>> writeDocument [] n)
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. One can use `mapM`, but with hxt's newtypeomania, that'd be rather complicated and there's got to be a better way.

Comment: Eh ... not sure if missing context.

Comment: Your comment to my (now deleted) answer, "... I don't think that's the way..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`root`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/9.2.0/doc/html/Text-XML-HXT-DOM-XmlNode.html) and [`constA`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/9.2.0/doc/html/Control-Arrow-ArrowList.html) to make an document root arrow out of your node:

```
runX (root [] [constA x] >>> writeDocument [] "test.xml")
```

This should work as expected.

Comment: great! thanks :) is this the way that should be used? or is there a *better* way to achieve this?

Comment: Ideally you'd use the arrow pipes all the way through (from `readDocument` to `writeDocument`), but assuming you've got an `XmlTree` that you want to write, I think this approach is reasonable.

Comment: I am not sure a 'all way through' pipe will work. I have tried something like this: `runX ( readDocument [withCurl [],withExpat yes] "file.xml" >>> getElement "Tag" >>> getAttrValue "DEF" &&& this >>> arr (\ (n,x) -> writeDocument [] n))` and while it doesn't throw any error it has no effect.

Comment: @Florian: Two problems with that code: you need a document root for `writeDocument`, and an `applyA` since you now have nested arrows—i.e., `runX . applyA $ readDocument [withCurl [],withExpat yes] "file.xml" >>> getElement "Tag" >>> getAttrValue "DEF" &&& this >>> arr (\ (n,x) -> root [] [constA x] >>> writeDocument [] n)`