# I need a function that operates on child nodes

Tags: haskell, hxt

I'm working on the project I was working on here:

[How do I make a do block return early?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441956/how-do-i-make-a-do-block-return-early)

I went with the monad transformer method at my function looks something like this:

```
scrapePost :: String -> IO ()                                                   
scrapePost url = liftM (fromMaybe ()) . runMaybeT $ do
  doc <- lift $ fromUrl url
  -- get a bunch of stuff from the page 
  -- send it to the db
  replies <- lift . runX $ doc >>> css ".post.reply"
  -- here is the problem
  mapM_ (parseReply url (fromJust page_id)) replies
  -- here is the problem
```

`parseReply` is the function I need, but I can't seem to get it right.

Here is my feeble attempt to start that function:

```
parseReply :: String -> String -> XNode -> Maybe ()                                
parseReply url op_id reply = do                                                    
  reply_id <- runX $ reply ! "id"                                                     
  return ()
```

BTW, I am using HandsomeSoup

I will operate just like the `scrapePost` function with a set css rules to scrape, drop replies that don't have all the values, and send them to the db.

I want to use `mapM` because my hope is to replace all the `mapM` with `liftIO` and see the performance difference.

**[UPDATE]**

So it turns out I didn't need to do any type acrobatics, I just needed a way to turn the reply node into a root node which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9435726/334632).

Since `parseReply` is only used in the `MaybeT IO ()` context, its type doesn't need to change and `scrapePost` can stay the same.

`parseReply` becomes:

```
toRoot :: ArrowXml a => XmlTree -> a n XmlTree                                     
toRoot node = root [] [constA node]                                                

parseReply :: String -> String -> XmlTree -> MaybeT IO ()                          
parseReply url op_id reply = do                                                    
  let node = toRoot reply                                                        
  reply_id <-  lift . liftM (`atMay` 0) $ runX $ node >>> css "div" ! "id"
  guard (isJust reply_id)                                                        
  return ()
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's take a look at the type of your "monad runner"

```
liftM (fromMaybe ()) . runMaybeT :: MaybeT IO () -> IO ()
```

So we'll need each line of the do block to have type `MaybeT IO ()`. Since `mapM_ :: (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()` we have `parseReply url (fromJust page_id)` needing to have the type `MaybeT IO ()` not just `Maybe ()`.

Fortunately, as one might hope, it's easy to inject a pure `Maybe` into `MaybeT IO`

```
parseReplyT :: Monad m => String -> String -> XNode -> MaybeT m ()
parseReplyT url op_id = MaybeT . return . parseReply url op_id
```